# Open source android app wont run via Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, adt

I am a total beginner to programming. I am looking to play about editing bits of a basic open source app (created by someone else) to help me get the hang of different parts of the process of app development.

The app I am downloading can be found here: http://www.sourcecodester.com/5903/android-employee-directory.html

I have downloaded an apk version which works fine via Youwave, however I want to 'test' (i.e. run) the source code version via Eclipse/ADT. Without editing the code whatsoever I try to do this and it fails stating there are errors in the code that prevent it running. I don't understand how this can be the case given it is a working beginners app published by someone who obviously knows more than me about what they're doing (proof: the apk version works fine), and given I have not yet edited anything there is no possibility my errors have broken the app. What is going on? How can I make the app test run?

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Please post the errors.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a MainActivity class in the code, which the application wants to launch on startup, based on the entry in AndroidManifest.xml.

To fix this, assuming the application should open to the EmployeeList class on first launch, replace the line:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.employeedirectory.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

in AndroidManifest.xml with:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.employeedirectory.EmployeeList"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

If it isn't the case that you want to launch the EmployeeList then replace that with whichever class should be launched on startup.

The manifest also appears to be missing entries for each of the other Activities in the application. You will need to add those to the manifest before you can launch them.